# How can I convert this Java Date Mon Mar 18 00:00:00 VET 2002 to a regular ISO or Javascript date?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am receiving from a service a Java date formatted like **Mon Mar 18 00:00:00 VET 2002**. How can I convert this date to a regular ISO or Javascript date? Or even have the momentjs library convert it?

Moment gives me the warning: *deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java is *not* (≠) JavaScript.

Comment: What does `VET` mean? Is this a timezone? Please share a text-based [mcve] of the code being used.

Comment: @LightningMcQueen never said as much.

Comment: @Hols You included *both* tags?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes, VET is the venenzuelan timezone. Not sure what example I could provide, it is just a string a service I am using returns along with other data.

Comment: Does that service return all its date/time information in VET timezone?

Comment: @trincot no, it returns another field with it's date in a different format. I don't have control over the service itself.

Comment: A different format? Then your question is too broad.

Comment: I don't see how it is too broad, @trincot: How can I convert this Java date (Mon Mar 18 00:00:00 VET 2002) into an ISO or regular javascript date?

Comment: Yes, that is OK, but you say that there are other **formats** too. Do you really mean formats? or just other timezone codes, in the same format?

Comment: I said in response to your question that the service returns other fields that have date values in other formats. But those other fields are not really what I am trying to convert.

Comment: OK, then back to my original question: does the field *of your interest* always use the VET timezone, or not?

Comment: @trincot yes it is always in that timezone.

Comment: I think what OP wants is String -> String So, His `VET` format to `UTC` format using `moment.js` @Hols you have to be explicit if this is what you want. If that's the case this has nothing at all to do with `Java`. It's not a `Java date` - Like, there is nothing specific to Java about the date. If a `C#` app produced the same string, you'd still want it converted

Answer (score 2):

As you indicate in comments that the timezone for this particular field is always VET, we can assume the -04:00 timezone. The other terms can be parsed, where the 3-letter month can be looked up in a string and converted to a month number. From that an [ECMAScript compliant date-time string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#date_time_string_format) can be formed, which can be given to a `Date` constructor:

```js
function toDateTimeStringFormat(s) {
    const regex = /^... (...) (\d\d?) (\d\d?:\d\d:\d\d) VET (\d+)$/;
    const [, monthname, day, time, year] = s.trim().match(regex);
    const month = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec".indexOf(monthname) / 3 + 1;
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}T${time}-04:00`
           .replace(/(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)/g, "0$&"); // pad single digit numbers
}

const tests = [
    'Mon Mar 18 00:00:00 VET 2002',
    'Sat Jul 8 00:00:00 VET 2023'
];

for (const test of tests) {
    const dateStr = toDateTimeStringFormat(test);
    console.log(dateStr, new Date(dateStr));
}
```

This regex to parse the input may need adjustment in case your input turns out to be slightly different. For instance, if the input ends with an extra point at the end, you have to cope with that in the regex.

As you can see, it requires the "VET" timezone to be present in the input. If there is any deviation, the function will run into an error or may return an unexpected string (like when the month is not recognised, it will default to 00).